# calling defined functions in another function in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, function

I am just starting to code. Got a job as a junior developer thanks to other skills. And right now I am self studying to learn Python 3, Django and React. I am 3 weeks in, and i like it thus far. 
While learning to code i found some exercises to do and gave my own swing at it. So I am trying to make kind of a lite rpg, where the player and comp chooses an attack and it gets executed in random order.

But i am having trouble making the attacks and everything else to be in callable functions. I could write out the whole code to the length of times, but i want to make it easier to code and expand on. This is what i have at the moment. I think the mistake is in the parameters in the functions? Which make some local instead of global values.

anyways, thank you in advance.

So i tried a lot of different parameters in different places. cant figure it out. also tried to call the move functions inside the player_move function.

```
import random


def tackle():
    dmg = random.randint(150, 280)
    return dmg


def bite():
    dmg = random.randint(110, 350)
    return dmg


def heal():
    dmg = random.randint(130, 260)
    return dmg


player_health = 1000
comp_health = 1000
alive = True


def player_move():
    move = input("Use one of the following moves: \n"
                 "1. Tackle\n"
                 "2. Bite\n"
                 "3. Heal\n"
                 "Choose the Move: ")
    if move == 1 or move == "Tackle" or move == "tackle":
        comp_health -= tackle()
    elif move == 2 or move == "Bite" or move == "bite":
        comp_health -= bite()
    elif move == 3 or move == "Heal" or move == "heal":
        comp_health -= heal()
    return comp_health

player_move()
print(comp_health)
```

Answer (score 0):

So i figured a few things out. Most of it was in the scope of the functions. Had to call the functions before using them. I ended up rewriting most of it, but got it to work. (edit) The question still stands though. How can I call a function out of scope??